# Populate model parameter with the openid_identifier selected in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, openid, openid-selector

I have been using openid selector to implement openid login on a web site following the tutorial [here](http://blog.tchami.com/post/ASPNET-MVC-2-and-OpenID.aspx).

It all works ok but the openid_identifier is read in the controller from the request like so `Request.Form["openid_identifier"]` and I wanted to instead add the selected openid_identifier to the view model and have it set in there instead (so I can add other things to the view model or so I can test the controller more easily).

Can I do this?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does changing

```
public ActionResult Authenticate(string returnUrl)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Authenticate(String returnUrl, String openid_identifier)
```

do it for you?

Comment: Thanks Naraen, this allows me to avoid using the request to read the data which makes the testing easier, and is a suitable workaround until I can figure out how to set the value of a property on a model